# PHP Codeigniter application in windows server

Tags: php, codeigniter, windows-server-2012-r2

[I tried to run PHP Codeigniter application in windows server but I am getting the error as shown below. I am new to windows server but the same application run well when deployed in linux server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8N7C.png)

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'apac.ci_session' doesn't exist

SELECT `data` FROM `ci_session` WHERE `id` = '7sial0ldti1jrkd1k2hji6k5nrdn6gja'

Filename: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/apac/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll' (tried: ext\php_wincache.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), ext\php_php_wincache.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.))

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: session_write_close(): Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: )

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Answer (score 0):

Is the DLL present in the C:\php\ext folder?

If it isn't, you can refer to this link to get a copy http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.installation.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may mark this as answer if it helps you, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

IIS recently removed the ability to add php_wincache.dll and is not really needed.
I found I could eliminate the CodeIgniter WARNING by making a small change to:
...\system\libraries\Cache\Cache.php  Line #63

```
/***  Removed wincache -- 
* protected $valid_drivers = array(
*   'apc',
*   'dummy',
*   'file',
*   'memcached',
*   'redis',
*   'wincache'
*));
*/
protected $valid_drivers = array(
   'apc',
   'dummy',
   'file',
   'memcached',
   'redis'
);
```

I also edited the system\core\Exceptions.php:

```
public function show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{
    /*  Added if to ignore wincache fake Warning 12/12/22 - Damon */
    if (strpos($message, 'wincache')=== false) {
        $templates_path = config_item('error_views_path');
        /* rest of the code */
    }
}
```